# Chrome InvalidStateError while using SessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, session

I have several expandable divs in a project I am creating and am saving their state between pages. My code is as follows and works perfectly in Firefox and IE.

On page load, get the existing saved dashboard state and open the divs that were previously saved:

```
$(function () {
    //Load the saved dashboard state
    var dashState;
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem("dashState")) {
        dashState = new Object({
            saved: []
        });
        sessionStorage.setItem("dashState", JSON.stringify(dashState));
    } else {
        dashState = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("dashState"));
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < dashState.saved.length; i++) {
        var currClient = $(dashState.saved[i]);
        $(currClient.selector).css("display", "block");
        var parent = $(currClient.selector).parent();
        $(parent[0].children[0]).attr("src", "/Content/minus.ico");
        $(parent[0].children[0]).attr("alt", "minus");
    }
});
```

When a user clicks the expand button, save which div was expanded (or minimized) and add/remove it from the currently saved session.

```
function expandClick(clicked, target) {
    var dashState = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("dashState"));
    if (clicked.attr("src") == "/Content/minus.ico") {
        target.css("display", "none");
        clicked.attr("src", "/Content/plus.ico");
        clicked.attr("alt", "plus");
        //Remove from dashboard saved state
        dashState.saved.pop(target);
    } else {
        target.css("display", "block");
        clicked.attr("src", "/Content/minus.ico");
        clicked.attr("alt", "minus");
        //Add to dashboard saved state
        dashState.saved.push(target);
    }
    sessionStorage.setItem("dashState", JSON.stringify(dashState));
}
```

Like I said, works great in Firefox and IE. My problem is Chrome. When the very last line of code executes, `sessionStorage.setItem("dashState", JSON.stringify(dashState));` I get the error "Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable." I'm confused because in the debugger, dashState has been initiated. Is this a scope problem I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an issue occurs when you push the jQuery objects to the list and try and stringify them. It is possible that parts of the object are cleaned up by the browser as once you stringify them, they fall out of scope (though usually stringifying DOM elements results in a circular reference exception). I'd suggest trying assigning a unique ID to each element and storing that in your saved list:

```
dashState.saved.pop(target[0].id);
dashState.saved.push(target[0].id);
```